# Handle ViewExpiredException before handle() method in ExceptionHandlerWrapper is called

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-filters, viewexpiredexception, facescontext

I've already searched via google and on stackoverflow, but could not find any similar problem to mine.

In my project I'm handling a ViewExpiredException properly and show a custom page to the user that the current session has timed out. This works great, but I want to do something BEFORE this message gets shown to the user. Actually I'm working with 2 different sessions here, one on the frontend side and one on the backend, so the idea is to NOT start a new backend session when the current one timed out.
Is there any possibility to fetch the ViewExpiredException while I'm inside the doFilter method, so I do not start a new backend session (simply because it is not needed)? Or is there any other way?

I already tried to fetch the current context via

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
```

But obviously the context is null, because the session timed out.
Inside the ExceptionHandlerWrapper I have access to the UnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents, but this does not help me here since I need this information earlier.

I hope I made my problem clear enough.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Regards
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `ViewExpiredException` is thrown when a POST request is fired while the session is timed out. So, this should do in the filter:

```
boolean post = "POST".equals(request.getMethod());
boolean timedout = request.getRequestedSessionId() != null && !request.isRequestedSessionIdValid();

if (post && timedout) {
    // JSF will guaranteed throw ViewExpiredException when state saving is set to server.
}
```

But this does not cover all possible cases. `ViewExpiredException` can also occur when the session hasn't timed out. For example, when the client has passed an invalid `javax.faces.ViewState` parameter, or when the associated view has been pruned from the LRU map which can by default hold 15 views. This is however not detectable inside a servlet filter before `FilterChain#doFilter()` is called. You really need to be inside the JSF context. You could do the backend session creating job in a `PhaseListener`. E.g. in beforephase of apply request values phase, which is guaranteed to be invoked only when there's a vaild view.

By the way, the `FacesContext` is not `null` in the filter because the session has timed out, but because the `FacesServlet`, the one responsible for creating it, hasn't been invoked yet at that point. You know, filters run before servlets.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed description.